# What is the meaning of EXC_ARM_DA_DEBUG when debugging on iOS 9.2 and connect to XCode 6.2?

Tags: iphone, debugging, xcode6, ios9

My iOS app was developed on `XCode 6.2` and old iOS that has Version8.2 and older versions. Right now, I tried to connect iOS device with version9.2 to `XCode 6.2`. While debugging, it just blocked me and show this error message:

> dyld`gdb_image_notifier: 0x1fe92094:  bx     lr Thread 1:
>   EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_DA_DEBUG, subcode=0x1fe9e398)

Don't know what this means. Anybody can explain it.